# Cannot highlight the geometries in polygon

Tags: openlayers-3

I have a few geometries in map, the point is in polygon, I can highlight the polygon, but the point cannot be highlighted because of polygon enclose it. In new openlayers3 `ol.featureoverlay` has been removed, If have some ways to solve it, here is an [example](http://jsfiddle.net/Wenhua1224/6ysd6s2q/4/).

Answer (score 0):

I updated that plunker to [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jonataswalker/ad8rzsyn/) to work against newer OL versions. It is not ready yet but perhaps it does what you need.

Basically I get a coefficient by comparing `pointer` coordinate with the coordinate of the closest feature. If this coefficient is short enough than add the feature to a `ol.Collection`.

To get the selected feature (for now, see https://github.com/openlayers/ol3/issues/4459) you can listen to collection changes:

```js
collection.on('change:length', function(evt) {
  if (collection.getLength() > 0) {
    var feature = hoverInteraction.getFeatures().item(0);
    // can be also
    //var feature = collection.item(0);
  }
});
```